# Android - Locations got from LocationClient doesn't support speed

Tags: android, gps, location, location-client

I'm using the new Google LocationClient to retrieve geo locations. And I need to get speed for each point (location).
What I'm doing now is:

```
if (mLocationClient == null) {
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, mLocationCallback, mLocationCallback);
    mLocationCallback.setLocationClient(mLocationClient);
    if (!(mLocationClient.isConnected() || mLocationClient.isConnecting())) {
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }
}
```

Where mLocationCallback is an instance of

```
public class LocationCallback implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {}
```

In the function,

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: location == null");
            return;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Location@ " + location.getLatitude() + ","
                   + location.getLongitude() + ", Altitude: "
                   + location.getAltitude() + "(" + location.hasAltitude()
                   + ")" + " Velocity: " + location.getSpeed() + " m/s("
                   + location.hasSpeed() + ")");
        }
}
```

However, everytime `location.hasSpeed()` gives `false`. It seems that only GPS provider gives speed. I'm sure my GPS is on but it might never be used.
Is there a way to force LocationClient to use GPS provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to force LocationClient to use GPS provider?

No, because the point of `LocationClient` is for it to blend data from multiple sources (GPS, WiFi, cell towers, sensors, etc.).

If you need speed, use `LocationManager` and work with the `GPS_PROVIDER`, or anything else the `Criteria` says supports speed (e.g., Galileo, someday, maybe).

Comment: Yes you're right. Luckily I only need to collect points at a fixed rate. So I ended up calculating the distance between 2 adjacent locations divided by time interval. :)

Comment: Just a note on @XiangxinSun's method - when LocationClient reports a location without Speed (e.g. from WiFi) at a high frequency, the LatLng from one point to the next may not change, so your speed may end up being calculated out at 0 anyway.

Comment: @CommonsWare [LocationClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) is deprecated. Look at this answer for current options: [LocationManager or Location Service API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266362/android-google-maps-api-location/27195920#27195920)