# locationListener + manager vs. GoogleServices + locationClient

Tags: java, android, location, google-play-services

I want to get my device position.

sometimes current position on demand and sometimes periodically every 5 mins

(even when the application is not visible).

I have used LocationListener + LocationManager.

```
   LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            locListener);

   LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            locListener);
```

but i see in Android dev site the use of [LocationClient](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Why should I opt one of them over the other?

is LocationClient for GPS provider only?

Answer (score 0):

The question your are asking has been partly answered here 
[LocationClient vs LocationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916273/locationclient-vs-locationmanager)
Hope that helps