# Remove Location Listener

Tags: android, dialog, location

I want after open dialog and click on location button, detect user's location and show user's location and then user dismiss dialog, location listener removes and not get location from `onLocationChanged`, I try used `locationManager.removeUpdate(locListener)`on override `dismiss` but not any chance and location after dismiss again shows! why? How can i detect user's location after show dialog and after detect location, location listener remove? Thanks

EDIT:

> ```
> public class DialogTest extends Dialog implements
> android.view.View.OnClickListener {
> ```

```
Context context;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

Location location;

public DialogTest(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.context = context;
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_dialog);

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background_dialog);

    firstAccessLocation=true;

    setCancelable(true);
    initialize();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    findAddress();
}

private void findAddress() {
    // if (gpsCheckBox.isChecked()) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    // }
}

private void stopTracking(){
    if(locationManager!=null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void dismiss() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stopTracking();
    gpsTurnOff();
    super.dismiss();
}

public class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(location!=null)
            Log.e("location", location.getLatitude()+"");
        location = loc;
        if (location != null&& firstAccessLocation) {
            setAddress(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            firstAccessLocation=false;
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("location", "changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post some of your current code?

Comment: Thanks. I add some code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

In new code you should use `LocationClient` rather then `LocationManager`. It's more efficient in getting the location with minimal energy(battery drain) with greater accuracy. Look here [LocationClient vs LocationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916273/locationclient-vs-locationmanager). With `LocationClient` established you can call `getLastLocation()` which provide you last location and doesn't start cyclic location updates. 
If you want to stick with `LocationManager` use `requestSingleUpdate (String provider, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)` method to get only one newest location from it.

Comment: I want get exact user location not last location. Last location some times is not correct location. My question is, i want to remove update detecting location but i don't know how can i do this.

Comment: So like I wrote in edit, use `requestSingleUpdate` method and you will not have to remove location updates.

Comment: requestSingleUpdate is not available! I should use this in GPSLocationListener or in DialogTest class?

Comment: `public void requestSingleUpdate (String provider, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)` is a method of LocationManager so use it instead of `requestLocationUpdates` in your code.

Comment: Thanks. And what is looper? and how can fill this?

Comment: `Looper` is a class used to run a message loop for a thread. You should pass your main thread looper here. To get it call `Looper.getMainLooper()`.

Comment: requestSingleUpdate use in api level 9+ but i support api level 8+ :( Please say another way :)

Comment: Well first of all look at [Android Dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net). Devices with API below 10 is approximately 0.7%. Is it really worth it? :) However as an another solution I recommend using `LocationClient` and `LocationRequest` classes. They are a part of Google Play API. Besides last location use can also ask it for location updates with `requestLocationUpdates` method.