# Location Client returned location not returning the speed

Tags: android, location, android-location, location-client

In my android application i am using **location manager** to get the location . It works fine in below **android 4.0**.But in the later versions of android I find it **difficult to get the network location** in this Location manager API.That is **location changed event for network provider** is not called.

so I have **moved to Location Client** which uses play services to give accurate location to the application but in this API **network location problem was solved**.It gives some accurate locations to my application but it always **return location.getSpeed() as Zero**.

so is there any way to get speed value while using location client API.some body help me to sort this thing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Play services `LocationClient` is a fused provider and will pick a location on your behalf from a mixture of the GPS on the device as well as the network based provider. It does this through a mixture of criteria and based on available resources. As a result there is no guarantee of the speed being set on the location that you receive and unfortunately it [cannot be forced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239006/android-locations-got-from-locationclient-doesnt-support-speed).

You will either have to switch back to using the `LocationManager` if you want to receive the speed with the location, or calculate the speed based on the location you are receiving from the device in your own code.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I found later that the network location problem exists so I moved to Location Manger itself..